# Check if stage exists in Dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have a CI script that builds Dockerfiles. My plan is that unit tests should be run in a `test` stage in each Dockerfile, for example:

```
FROM alpine AS build
WORKDIR /app
COPY src .
...

FROM build AS test
RUN mvn clean test

FROM build AS package
COPY --from=build ...
```

So, for a given Dockerfile, I would like to check if it has a `test` stage and, if so, run `docker build --target test ...`. If it doesn't have a `test` stage, I don't want to run `docker build` (which would fail).

**How can I check if a Dockerfile contains a certain stage without actually building it?**

<sup><sub>I do realize this question has some [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/) vibes to it, so feel free to enlighten me. But I also think the question can be generally useful anyway.</sub></sup>

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to shy away from trying to parse the Dockerfile since there are a lot of ways to inject false positives or negatives. E.g.

```
RUN echo \
FROM base as test
```

or

```
FROM base \
  as test
```

So instead, I'm going to favor letting docker do the hard work, and modifying the file to not fail on a missing test. This can be done by adding a test stage to a file even when it already as a test stage. Whether you want to put this at the beginning or end of the Dockerfile depends on whether you are running buildkit:

```
$ cat df.dup-target
FROM busybox as test
RUN exit 1
FROM busybox as test
RUN exit 0

$ DOCKER_BUILDKIT=0 docker build --target test -f df.dup-target .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  20.99kB
Step 1/2 : FROM busybox as test
 ---> be5888e67be6
Step 2/2 : RUN exit 1
 ---> Running in 9f96f42bc6d8
The command '/bin/sh -c exit 1' returned a non-zero code: 1

$ DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1 docker build --target test -f df.dup-target .
[+] Building 0.1s (6/6) FINISHED
 => [internal] load build definition from df.dup-target                                                                                                                 0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 114B                                                                                                                                    0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                       0.0s
 => => transferring context: 34B                                                                                                                                        0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/busybox:latest                                                                                                       0.0s
 => [test 1/2] FROM docker.io/library/busybox                                                                                                                           0.0s
 => CACHED [test 2/2] RUN exit 0                                                                                                                                        0.0s
 => exporting to image                                                                                                                                                  0.0s
 => => exporting layers                                                                                                                                                 0.0s
 => => writing image sha256:8129063cb183c1c1aafaf3eef0c8671e86a54f795092fa7a918145c14da3ec3b                                                                            0.0s
```

Then you could append the always successful test at the beginning or end, passing that modified Dockerfile to stdin for the `docker build` to process:

```
$ cat df.simple                   
FROM busybox as build
RUN exit 0   

$ cat - df.simple <<EOF | DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1 docker build --target test -f - .
FROM busybox as test                                                                                                                                                        
RUN exit 0                                                                                                                                                                  
EOF                                                                                                                                                                         
[+] Building 0.1s (6/6) FINISHED                                                                                                                                            
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                    0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 109B                                                                                                                                    0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                       0.0s
 => => transferring context: 34B                                                                                                                                        0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/busybox:latest                                                                                                       0.0s
 => [test 1/2] FROM docker.io/library/busybox                                                                                                                           0.0s
 => CACHED [test 2/2] RUN exit 0                                                                                                                                        0.0s
 => exporting to image                                                                                                                                                  0.0s
 => => exporting layers                                                                                                                                                 0.0s
 => => writing image sha256:8129063cb183c1c1aafaf3eef0c8671e86a54f795092fa7a918145c14da3ec3b                                                                            0.0s
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple `grep` invocation:

```sh
egrep -i -q '^FROM .* AS test$' Dockerfile
```

You also might consider running your unit tests outside of Docker, before you start building containers.  (Or, if your CI system supports running steps inside containers, use a container to get a language runtime, but not necessarily run the Dockerfile.)  You'll still need a Docker-based setup to run larger integration tests, but you can run these on your built production-ready containers.

Comment: I've actually considered that exact `grep` command, but I didn't feel confident in it with respect to false positives, false negatives, case-sensitivity and whatnot. But maybe it is a good solution then, since you're also suggesting it!

Comment: I think `-E` is necessary for the regex to work. `-i` would also make sense because both Dockerfile keywords and stage names are case-insensitive.

Comment: I made both changes in the answer.